# Finding cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ of prime order

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

It can be proven that multiplicative group of integers modulo $N$ defined as

$$\mathbb{Z}^\times_N = \{ i\in \mathbb Z : 1\leq i\leq N−1\; \text{ and }\; \gcd(i,N)=1 \}$$

is cyclic for a prime $N$ and that if it is of prime order, then every non-identity element in the group is a generator of this group.

How can I find such $N$?

I wrote a simple program and brute-forced for $i \in \mathbb Z; i\in [1, 300 000]$ and found no group of prime order so far.

Comment: How about $N=3$?

Comment: If $N$ is prime, then your group has $N-1$ elements , which  is a prime only for $N=3$

Comment: Note that the condition $\gcd(i, N)$ is vacuous if $N$ is prime and $1 \le i \le N-1$, so as per Peter's comment your group has $N-1$ elements.

Comment: In case you are confused by why only $N = 3$ works, note that the **only** two consecutive integers which are both prime are $\{2, 3\}$.  You That's because $2$ is the **only** *even* prime.

Comment: I was rejecting $N = 3$ as a trivial case, heh :) So just to make sure I properly understand implications here: for $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$, when looking for a generator, we must pick a random number from $[2, N-1]$ and check if it matches Euler's criterion? We can not select $N$ in such a way that we'll know upfront what the generator is. Is that correct?